# Why am I getting an "expected an expression" error when multiplying a variable by a constant in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

My code is below. When I replace line 23 with "newtons * 4.448", it works fine, but when I run the code as is, I get 2 error: "Expected an expression", and "syntax error: '='" on line 23. How can I fix this?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS = 4.448;

int main(void) {
    double newtons;
    double pounds;

    printf("Enter Newtons: ");

    scanf("%lf", &newtons);

    pounds = newtons * NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS;

    printf("%.2f", pounds);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After macro substitution the expression `pounds = newtons * NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS;` becomes `pounds = newtons * = 4.448;;` ... you should `define` without equals sign or semicolon.

Comment: Additionally, you can't use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** to validate the input succeeded, e.g. `if (scanf("&lf", &newtons) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid double value.\n", stderr); return 1; }` You can just add `/wd4996` as a compiler option to disable the CRT SECURE warnings, or `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` above your define for `NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS` (after nuking the `=` sign and the `';'`)

Comment: Could use a more precise value [4.4482216152605](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)#Product_of_avoirdupois_pound_and_standard_gravity) or `(0.45359237 * 9.80665)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `#define` is invalid instead of

```
#define NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS = 4.448;
```

do

```
#define NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS 4.448
```

Answer (score 1):

`#define`d constants aren't real variables - they are just text replacements. The `=` and `;` you have there are redundant (i.e. - wrong). Lose them and you should be OK:

```c
#define NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS 4.448
/* Here -----------------^-----^ */
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the equals sign in `#define NEWTONS_IN_POUNDS = 4.448;` most likely causes the issue. Try deleting the equals sign and the semicolon in that statement and it should fix the issue. Defining variables using `#define` is different then defining a variable normally.